# How do you find the value of x in this example?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I wish I could provide an image but I'll explain the best way I can.

There is a triangle that is not a $90^\circ$ triangle. It has two sides measured at 8 and 6 (units not specified). The other side is $x$. There are no angles whose measures are given. How do I find $x$? We are doing a topic on law of sines.

Law of cosines

$\displaystyle \large a^2 = b^2 + c^2 - 2bc \space \cos A$

$\displaystyle \large x^2 = 6^2 + 8^2 - 2(6)(8) \space \cos A$

<strike>x = Sqrt[4 Cos[A] ]</strike>

<strike>x = 2 Sqrt[ Cos[A] ]</strike>

$\displaystyle \large x^2 = -96\space \cos A + 100$

$\displaystyle \large x = \sqrt{100-96\space \cos A}$

Comment: $x$ should be $ x = \sqrt{100-96\cos A}$   and also As you see that x depends on angle $A$. It will give a range if you change angle $A$ . x will be in range  $2<x<14$.

Comment: Where does that value come from??

Comment: Please be careful that $100-96cosA$ is not equal to $4cosA$  . This is mathematically wrong  what you did in your question.

Comment: Oh yeah that completely slipped my mind!! Thanks for the save lol

Comment: Now what are the maximum and minimum values of $A$,  $\cos A$ and $x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not enough information to solve this problem.  To uniquely define $x$, you would need to know the angle opposite the side of length $x$ as any 2 triangles with a side of length 6, one of length 8, and a congruent angle between them would be congruent by SAS.  Although, it would probably be more appropriate to use the law of cosines in this case to solve for $x$.

Comment: Use the law of cosines? I'll show you what I tried in the edit.

Comment: I made the edit! :) Is it right?

Comment: @David Close.  You dropped a minus sign.  Also, you may want to call the angle measure $X$ to differentiate it from the length of the side.

Comment: Got it, is the edit right?

Comment: @David This length is a real value.  $i$ shouldn't appear in it.  It should be $\sqrt{100-96\cos X}$

Comment: i made the change

Answer (score 0):

By the triangle inequality $$2 \lt x \lt 14.$$

Since there is not a right angle, you can exclude $x=10$ and $x=\sqrt{28} \approx 5.291$.

Comment: Excuse my french, but.......huh?

Comment: The angle between the sides of length $8$ and $6$ could be almost nothing, in which case $x$ is almost as small as $8-6$, or anything up to $180^\circ$ in which case $x$ is almost $8+6$.  But since there is not right angle you need to exclude $\sqrt{8^2 \pm 6^2}$.

Comment: Henry mentions that if you dont know any angles and if you only know 2 sides .$|a-b|<x<|a+b|$  where $a$ and $b$ given sides , $x$ is unknown side in the triaangle. You will need to define an angle to define x, otherwise it will be just a range as given in the answer.

Comment: @Mathlover So there is no exact value but just an estimation?

Comment: Yes, you have just a range with given 2 sides. Please imagine you hold 2 pencils that one is 6 cm other 8cm. We can create max 14 cm line or 2 cm will remain if we put on each other parallel . if you define an angle between pencils then you will have other side fixed.